# The pirate treasure of Leatherback Atoll

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Furious the captain returns to the ship. He throws the blasted map onto the deck kicks at it, misses, and curses the crew for their incompetency. He swears and slams his entire weight into his cabin door. He is gone, for now.

A quiet suspenseful gloom settles over the ship. You walk over and reach for the map. Examining it carefully... you think you got it! Or at least you got something! There are some faded letters, you can just barely make them out.

[image: Leatherback Atoll]

You bravely approach the captain's cabin, knock, open the door and press forward. He's done away with crew for less when this angry. With one hand holding the map, and the other on the hilt of your saber, you push into the murky depths of the cabin.

Where should you dig for the treasure?

Comment: Amazing puzzle!

Comment: That island is 1,500 km across in either direction. That's nearly a continent

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This map

> can be cut apart at the rivers and put back together, like a jigsaw puzzle!
>
>  [image]

And if you then

> look at the area with turtles and tortoises in it, as the directions say, you can see an arrow made out of empty space between the trees!
>
>  [image]
>
>  So you should look at the tip of that arrow for the treasure. In the original map, that's roughly (88°, 25°).